# ViewModel / Controller Architecture. Could this be a final solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use ASP.NET MVC for a few years and building complex view models is always a struggle.

At the moment I have a View which displays a list of meetings and I have the problems:

1. Each meeting has an employer and a location. To solve this I just flattened the model.
2. The filter form has two fields: Date and Location.
   I would like to submit the filter values as a class so I can use Fluent Validation.
3. The filter's location list is filled with database data.
4. The Meeting list is built using a few parameters, namely: pageSize and pageNumber.
5. The model should include page title, description and other items for the view ...
   Or should I pass this items in some other way?

I have been trying to follow the idea of a Fat Model and a Lean Controller.

So I have the following controller with an Index action (HttpGet and HttpPost):

(NOTE: Dispatcher is used to send and receive messages which contains DTOs)

```
public partial class MeetingController : BaseController {

  public MeetingController(IDispatcher dispatcher) : base(dispatcher) {}

  [HttpGet]
  public virtual ActionResult Index(Int32 pageNumber = 1) {      
    MeetingIndexModel model = new MeetingIndexModelHandler(_dispatcher).Create();
    return View(model);
  } // Index

  [HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Index(MeetingIndexModel.Filter filter, Int32 p = 1) {

  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    MeetingIndexModel model = new MeetingIndexModelHandler(_dispatcher).Update();
    return View(Views.Index, model);
  } else {
    MeetingIndexModel model = new MeetingIndexModelHandler(_dispatcher).Create();
    return View(Views.Index, model);
  }

} // Index
```

So the model is a little bit complex because of all needed so I thought:

```
public class MeetingIndexModel {

  public IPagedList<ViewEntity> Entities { get; set; }
  public ViewFilter Filter { get; set; }
  public ViewHelper Helper { get; set; }   

  public class ViewEntity {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public String EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public String LocationName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  }

  public class ViewFilter {
    public String Location { get; set; }
    public String Stamp { get; set; }         
  }

  public class ViewHelper {
    public Page Page { get; set; }
    public SelectList Locations { get; set; }
  }

}
```

Entities are the Meetings which are flatten from DTO using AutoMapper;

Filter are the arguments used in filtering the meetings and passed in dispatcher.

Helper contains SelectLists and other parameters ...

Then I have a MeetingIndexHandler which creates, updates or even submits the view model.
The submit happens, for example, when creating or updating a meeting.

```
public interface IViewModelHandler<T> {
  T Create();
  T Update(T model);
  void Submit(T model);
}
```

Of course with MeetingIndexModel it makes no sense to have a Submit method.
So for start, in this case, the Submit method wouldn't make sense.

Finally, I have the

```
public class MeetingIndexModelHandler : IViewModelHandler<MeetingIndexModel> {

  private IDispatcher _dispatcher;

  public ScheduleIndexModelHandler(IDispatcher dispatcher) { 
    _dispatcher = dispatcher;
  }

  public ScheduleIndexModel Create() {

    IList<MeetingDTO> meetings = _dispatcher.GetMeetings(DateTime.UtcNow, pageSize, pageNumber);

    // Map MeetingDTO to MeetingIndexModel.ViewEntity
    // Call GetLocations to get locations from database into Helper.Locations

  } // Create

  private SelectList GetLocations(String currentLocation) {

  }
```

}

I found this approach removes a lot of code from controllers ...

But there are a few problems for which I am looking help:

1. The submit action not always make sense;
2. When I create a model I might need an argument such as a pageSize and pageNumber ... or an Id, or ...

   In theory I would add these parameters to Create method as arguments.
   But each case is a case so I wouldn't be able to use a a IViewModelHandler.
3. And then there are the missing data like page title, description and so on ...
   How do I pass this to the views? Adding another child class to ViewModel?

Does this approach qualifies for over engineering? What do you think?

If yes, what other approaches you are using to solve this problem?

**UPDATE 1 - I am already using a Service Layer: The dispacther**

Note that I already have a service layer (IDispatcher) which I use to get data from the database and so on ... For example, I use it like this:

```
FindMeetingsByDataQuery query = new FindMeetingsByDataQuery(DateTime.UtcNow);

FindMeetingsByDataReply reply = _dispacther.Send<FindMeetingsByDataReply>(query);

// Map reply.Models to my View Models
```

Is it clear now?

So what I need is a way to move this logic (communication with service layer) to build the view models away from the controllers.

**UPDATE 2 - Approach using only the ViewModel and not the ViewModelHandler**

Another approach would be to have all the logic of filling the ViewModel inside the ViewModel instead of using a ViewModel Handler. So in Controller I have:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index(Int32 pageNumber = 1) {      
  MeetingIndexViewModel model = new MeetingIndexViewModel(_dispatcher);
  model.Create(pageNumber, 20, DateTime.UtcNow);
  return View(model);
} // Index
```

And the MeetingIndexViewModel is:

```
public class MeetingIndexViewModel : ViewModel {

  private IDispatcher _dispatcher;

  public IPageList<EntityModel> Entities { get; set; }
  public FilterModel Filter { get; set; }
  public HelperModel Helper { get; set; }

  public MeetingIndexViewModel(IDispatcher dispatcher) {
    _dispatcher = dispatcher;
  }

  public void Create(Int32 pageNumber, Int32 pageSize, DateTime date) {

    FindMeetingsByDateQuery query = new FindMeetingsByDateQuery(date, pageNumber, pageSize);

    FindMeetingByDateReply reply = _dispatcher.Send<FindMeetingByDateReply>(query);

    IEnumerable<MeetingIndexViewModel.EntityModel> entities = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<FindMeetingByDateReply.MeetingModel>, IEnumerable<MeetingIndexViewModel.EntityModel>>(reply.Meetings);

    Entities = new PagedList(entities);
    Filter = new FilterModel { Date = date.ToString() };
    Helper = new HelperModel { 
      PageSize = pageSize, 
      PageNumber = pageNumber, 
      Locations = _GetLocations(x.Filter.Location) 
    };

} // Create

public void Submit() {
  // In cases where a ViewModel must be sent to the business layer for saving than it is done here. Otherwise this method is removed.
}

private SelectList _GetLocations(Int32? selected) {

  GetLocationsQuery query = new GetLocationsQuery();
  GetLocationsReply reply = _dispatcher.Send<GetLocationsReply>(query);
  return new SelectList(reply.Locations.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).ToList(), "Id", "Name", selected);
} // _GetLocations

public class EntityModel {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String EmployeeId { get; set; }
  public String EmployeeName { get; set; }
  public String LocationName { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
} // EntityModel

public class FilterModel {      
  public Int32? Location { get; set; }
  public String Date { get; set; }      
} // FilterModel

public class HelperModel {
  public Int32 PageSize { get; set; }
  public Int32 PageSize { get; set; }
  public SelectList Locations { get; set; }    
} // HelperModel
```

}

So this way I remove all the logic of building the viewmodel from the controller and pass it to the viewmodel itself. Is this acceptable? Now it is not only a POCO.

**UPDATE 3 - Approach using the ViewModel and a custom ViewModelHandler**

```
public class MeetingIndexViewModelHandler {
  public MeetingIndexViewModel Create(Int32 pageNumber, Int32 pageSize, DateTime date) {
    // Code to create the ViewModel
  }
  // Code to update the ViewModel
  // Code to submit the ViewModel

}
```

I believe having ViewModelHandler from an interface makes everything hard because each view model is a view model.

**UPDATE 4 - Leaving the code in the controller**

Another approach is, as in 3 making the ViewModel just a POCO, and instead of having an Handler just leaving the code in the Controller. In general the code is not much but sometimes it can be ...

**NOTE:** 
What do you think, from your experience and from I posted, a good approach would be?

Comment: These kind of questions actually belong on [**CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend MVVM (Model-View-View Model) design pattern for this.  What MVVM does it adds new wrapper VM on top of Model, which allows you to keep your model (DTO) clean, but you can add extra properties such as Title, Description, ...  This will allow you to keep your Model clean and they can be shared between multiple VMs.

I would keep all actions in VM, and have model as DTO.  Most of the time each action would have it's own VM, but most of the time each VM of the same controller would share the same Model.

Comment: You mean, one ViewModel for all controller actions? At the moment I have one ViewModel per action ... Could you provide some code example looking at my code?

Comment: This is pretty much how I do most of my MVC stuff - I prefer having the controller do web-specific stuff such as deciding which view to use/redirecting etc. but have my business logic in an MVVM layer on top of the model. This way you can bind to VM properties in the view and you have lean controllers that don't need business logic in them. You can also have more complex bindings and model-derived properties without needing to place logic in the view

Comment: @MDMoura, most of the time for the same controller actions' you will have the same Model.  In order to have share the same model you should not have any business logic there, just data (POCO).  But you will have (and like you said you have) ViewModel per Action.  ViewModel will be specific to that Action only.  It will contain business logic for that Action, and it might contain Model using Composition design pattern.

Comment: @Charleh Isn't this what am I doing? I have a ViewModel to wrap all classes needed for that view, either be models mapped and flatten by DTO's, filter models or helper models with SelectLists and so on ... Then the ViewModelHandler removes the business logic from the controllers. I don't add that logic to the ViewModel because I think it does not belong there. My problem is the Handler ... By using a common interface is becoming hard to make it adaptable to any view model. So I am looking for advice here. I am not sure I understand every answer I got. Sorry ...

Comment: @VladBezden In my opinion one ViewModel per action removes a lot of problems ... And you mean that in this case having the Business Logic in a ViewModel makes sense? So I wouldn't need the Handler? I am not really sure if a ViewModel should include the business logic even if it is a ViewModel per action. Of course it would make it much easier.

Comment: @MDMoura After reading more your comments, I think I start to understand more your issue.  I see that your Handler is more like Business Layer (BL).  "My problem is the Handler ... By using a common interface is becoming hard to make it adaptable to any view model".  Maybe you should not use common interface in this case?

Comment: I just updated my post ... My Business Layer is the Dispatcher. It is the dispatcher that is responsible to send query and receive replies with data. The dispacther is a service layer based on Request/Reponses and Commands. So, at the moment, I inject the dispatcher into controller, then I use it to get all the data and build the viewmodel. What happens is that the code in the controller sometimes gets a little bit big. So I was wondering if having a ViewModelHandler or, if your prefer, ViewModelBuilder/Submiter to move that code away from the controller ...

Comment: @MDMoura, I see now, and it make sense what you are doing. Since you want to keep "Lean Controller" you move all your logic to Handler, which is fine as well.  The only thing I'm not sure is to keep common interface, since like you already found it is not the case for all cases.  What you can do is: 1 - remove your generic interface and use separate interface for each handler. 2 - split your IViewModelHander in two parts, so you have one Common interface for all ViewModels, and second specific to each action and implement both interfaces in your Handler.

Comment: To be honest almost all ViewHandlers have different arguments in methods so separating into two parts might be not even an option. I just added a few updates with the different options. Can you comment on those? Thank You.

Comment: @MDMoura I think "Leaving the code in the controller" (Update 4) will work and make your code less complex.  
There are two design patterns on where you keep your methods.  One is in ViewModel and second you keep them on Business Layer (Dispatcher in your case).  You might consider second design pattern, where Controller will call BL (dispatcher) and it will populate and return Model (please notice, Model, not VM). When controller gets that Model it will create VM and using composition design patter set Model to VM (or you can populate each property via AutoMapper if you wish).

Comment: Doing this way you will keep separate Model as POCO object.  Your VM will be specific to your action and you can add any properties (Title, Description, ...) to it and you can share the same Model between all Controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, how about an approach where you keep the same interface but add an argument to the `Create` method that takes a `ViewModelArgs` base class:

```
public interface IViewModelHandler<T> {
  T Create(ViewModelArgs args);
  T Update(T model);
  void Submit(T model);
}
```

Then you can make the args a nested class in your `ViewModel`:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public class SomeViewModelArgs : ViewModelArgs
    { 
        public SomeViewModelArgs(string value) { // blah }
    }
}
```

And call like so:

```
SomeViewModel model = new SomeViewModelHandler(_dispatcher).Create(new SomeViewModel.SomeViewModelArgs("someValue"));
```

Trying to think of disadvantages here, possibly some issues when mocking/testing? Worth thinking about that, but it means you can keep your interface

**Edit**

Still, not sure what this gives you that you couldn't achieve just putting a constructor on the ViewModel.. can't the VM decide what it needs to get from the dispatcher?

It seems like a layer that doesn't really have any concerns of it's own

e.g. what does it have over:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Index(Int32 pageNumber = 1) 
{      
    MeetingIndexModel model = new MeetingIndexModel();
    model.GetData();
    return View(model);
}
```

or if dependency injected (where you can have the modelbinder call an 'after-resolve' method if you don't want to do data-related work in the constructor - you can also error handle better in there too):

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Index(Int32 pageNumber = 1, MeetingIndexModel model) 
{      
    return View(model);
}
```

Just not sure what the layer gives you.. can you explain what you think it's doing for you? Maybe I'm missing something from your intent

Comment: You use or Arguments is something I already considered but somehow I feel that I will start to loose control because everything starts to be really complex ... Filling the viewmodel properties inside the ViewModel, as you do, using a method GetData is an option I have been looking for. But you need to pass the dispacther, or any other service, to the viewmodel into the constructor. Is this acceptable? If yes than this is an option. I am just not sure.

Comment: If you are using dependency injection, you can get your container to inject the dispatcher into the ViewModel. If your ViewModel depends on the dispatcher to work, then it should take it as part of the constructor - pretty much the first rule of IoC, even if you aren't injecting dependencies using a framework/container, your VM depends on the object so it needs to take it as part of it's constructor

Comment: See Update 2. That is the question now. Should ViewModel be only a POCO and be filled with code in the controller actions? Or should I remove that code and added it to the ViewModel and, as you say add the Dispatcher into the constructors? BTW, can you inject a Dispatcher into a ViewModel when the ViewModel itself is not being injected?

Answer (score 0):

1. your view model looks good
2. i recommend to crate a base class for the Page Title / Description
3. I do not like the IViewModelHandler approach. It feels too much generic for me. I would prefer more specific service layer with clear and domain specific method names
4. Also consider using Dependency Injection which makes your code more testable

   ```
      
    public interface IScheduleService
    {
       void ScheduleMeeting(MeetingModel meeting);     
       MeetingModel GetMeeting(int meetingId);
    }
   ```

**Update**

Personally I would go only with the service layer without handlers. If you are using the service layer just for the website, then you can directly return View models from it. Your code will be simpler, more readable and you can always add more layers if they are needed. This way you can directly map db entities to your view models.

Comment: For (2) why not having MeetingIndexViewModel : IViewModel where IViewModel would have those base properties (Title, Description, etc)? What do you think?

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand all my code. The handler is just a builder / command around the viewmodel. I mean, I already have a service layer which is injected into the controller: IDispatcher. Dispacther is a Message / Command system. I just updated my answer to explain that.

Comment: @MDMoura Yes, IViewModel will be ok. Now i understand your architecture and feel a bit over-engineered to me:) read my answer for explanation

Comment: Yes, Handler seem a little bit over engineering to me to ... My doubt at the moment is: do I leave the code responsible for building the viewmodels in the controller or do I move them to inside the ViewModel. what do you think? I just added a few Updates. Note that mapping an Entity to a ViewModel is simpler. The problem is when the ViewModel also has filters and so on ... In those cases I map the Entities to one class of the View Model and the others are classes are filled with SelectLists and so on ...

Comment: NOTE: Everything is simple when mapping ModelDTO > ViewModel. The problem is when the view needs much more than that.

Comment: For me seems better to build the view model inside the controller.